Fermat principle: how did they know the speed of light in different mediums?
Pierre de Fermat derived his principle of least time by considering the path that light would take when traveling between two points. He postulated that light would follow the path that minimized the time taken to travel between these points.
My question is, how did Fermat(died 1665), or Snell (died 1626), know that light traveled slower in glass or water than in air?
The speed of light in water is 225 000 kps, about 75% the speed of light in a vacuum. I can't imagine any scientists of the time had any way to measure the speed, or measure a difference.
How did they know or measure the difference in speed?

A number of comments deleted. Please use comments to clarify or improve the question. To answer the question, please write an answer.


$\dots$ how did Fermat(died 1665), or Snell (died 1626), know that light traveled slower in glass or water than in air?

They didn't!
To fit the experimental observations with the principle of least time Fermat assumed that the speed of light was slower in the denser medium. This brought him in direct conflict with Descartes who assumed that the speed of light was faster in a denser medium as did Newton using his laws of motion much later. Refraction was not the only topic about which Fermat and Descartes did not see eye to eye.
In 1851 Fizeau measured the speed of light in water as being less than that in air.

Wow! I assumed they measured first and later came up with the principle.

Also, speed of sound wave in a metal is faster than air, right? So did Descartes and Newton both assume speed of light was faster in denser medium from experiments with solids of various density and the waves from hitting the solids?

That is why whenever I taught my students, I always made it exceedingly clear that, at their level of understanding, whether it is a speed up or slow down, is impossible to answer. It is only much later that we experimentally established proper evidence one way or the other. The rigour is not for the sake of the teacher; it is for the sake of the poor students being dumped a concrete theory on their heads.

+1 It was Ptolemy in the 2nd century who was the  first to explain that refraction observed at air-water and air-glass interfaces were due to a difference in density between the two media.

@AndyChow Descartes reasoning is now thought to be very poor and not really "scientific" whereas Newton used his principles of Mechanics to show predict the increase in the speed of light in a medium.

I had been under the impression that Newton believed the speed of light to be infinite. Would that be better stated as without limit (that is, adding energy to a light packet would increase the speed rather than the frequency as is now understood)?

@SoronelHaetir The wikipedia article about the speed of light has a section titled 'First measurement attempts' 'In his 1704 book Opticks, Isaac Newton reported Rømer's calculations of the finite speed of light and gave a value of "seven or eight minutes" for the time taken for light to travel from the Sun to the Earth' The wikipedia page provides a link to a resource with scanned pages of the book 'Opticks'. Speed of light: section XI. Rømer's observations

Even without being able to directly measure the speed of light, there was a nontrivial quantitative match of Fermat's principle with experiment. Empirical observations of refraction were summarized in Snell's law, $n_1\sin\theta_1 = n_2\sin\theta_2$, where $n$ is a property of the medium (index of refraction). The relative values of $n$ for different media were straightforward to measure.
Fermat's principle predicts refraction should obey $(1/v_1)\sin\theta_1 = (1/v_2)\sin\theta_2$. This matches Snell's law for all angles, provided the speed of light (likewise a property of the medium) follows $v \propto 1/n$. It is a nontrivial fact that there exists any assignment of a speed of light to each medium such that Fermat's principle of least time reproduces Snell's law for every possible angle of incidence.
Thus, Fermat effectively provided an argument (not conclusive, but with at least some evidence) that "light traveled slower in glass or water than in air".
One reason this was not conclusive is that, remarkably, Newton's corpuscular theory could also reproduce Snell's law, but with $v \propto n$, which would say light traveled faster in media than in vacuum.
